# Inserting a value to list according to a threshold value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list `a = [1,2,3,6,8,12,13,18,33,23]` and list `b=[]` that is empty. I need each value in list `a` compare with all the values in the list `b` by taking the difference of the new value from list `a` with all the contents of the list `b`. If the difference is grater than to the value of the threshold, it must insert to list `b` rather than skip to the next value in `a`, how can do that?

```
a =[1,2,3,6,8,12,13,18,33,23]
b=[] 
b.append(a[0])
for index in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(len(b)): 
        x = a[index] - b[i]

        if x > 1: 
            b.append(a[index]) 
            
print("\nOutput list is")
for v in range(len(b)):  
    print(b[v])
```

The desired output is:

```
output = [1,6,8,12,18,33,23]
```

To further clarify, in first time the list `b` have the first item from list `a`. I need to check if the `a[0]-b[0]>1`, then insert the value of `a[0]` in `b` list, and next if `a[1] - b[0]>1` then insert the `a[1]` in `b` list , and if `[[a[2] -b[0] >1] and [a[2]-b[1] > 1]]` then insert `a[2]` in b list and so on

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question by removing the code you have attempted to do. You agree with sharing your code according to the [license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) when posting. The code is an important part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the probable solution to the stated problem though the output is not matching with your desired outcome. But sharing on the basis of how I understood the problem.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 12, 13, 18, 33, 23]
b = []
b.append(a[0])

threshold = 1   # Set Threshold value

for index in range(len(a)):
    difference = 0
    for i in range(len(b)):
        difference = abs(a[index] - b[i])

        if difference > threshold:
            continue  # Keep comparing other values in list b
        else:
            break   # No need for further comparison

    if difference > threshold:
        b.append(a[index])

   

 print("\nOutput list is")
    print(b)
```

Output is:

```
Output list is
[1, 3, 6, 8, 12, 18, 33]
```

Also, I notice that after swapping the last two elements (33 <-> 23 ) of the list a as below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 12, 13, 18, 23, 33]
```

and running the same code. the output was near to your desired output:

```
Output list is
[1, 3, 6, 8, 12, 18, 23, 33]
```

This problem is very interesting now as I put myself into more investigation. And I found it a very interesting. Let me explain. First consider the list a as a list of integer numbers starting from 1 to N. For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

and set the threshold to 1

```
threshold = 1   # Set Threshold value
```

Now, run the programme with threshold = 1 and you will get the output:

```
Output list is
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

and if you rerun with threshold = 2, you will get the following output:

```
threshold = 2

Output list is
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
```

Basically, this programme is basically generating a hopping series of integer numbers where hopping is set to the threshold value.

Interesting!!! Isn't it???

Comment: Thank you very much, but if I have list like this 44.6
8.1
5.1
2.1
4.1
5.1
6.1
Why the output is just 44.6

Comment: it will work for that too. This programme is based on the threshold value that you set irrespective of the values in the list a.

Comment: let me think over it.

Comment: it will output only 44.6 because every other number after it is lesser than 44.6. thus the difference of each of them with 44.6 will not be greater than the threshold of 1 anyway.

Comment: could you please let me know what is expected outcome if a = [44.6, 8.1, 5.1, 2.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1]

Comment: I expected the output =[44.6, 8.1 ,5,1, 2,1]  and that what i need

Comment: do just one change in the programme as per the following: difference = a[index] - b[i] ==>> difference = abs(a[index] - b[i]) . apply abs() method on the difference logic. and that's it!!!

Comment: I just updated the main programme. Please check the use of abs() method fixed the problem.

Comment: That is because subtracting a higher number from a smaller number will give us a negative difference that will return false while testing condition difference > threshold. thus as we are interested here in knowing only if the difference between the number from list a and all the individual members of list b is higher than the threshold value irrespective of its order, we are interested always in a positive difference, thus I used abs() function. abs() function always returns an absolute value without considering its sign.